# How to get tags from a field automatically?

Tags: wordpress, tags, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I'm new to wordpress. I have created a field in wordpress (using advanced custom fields) and I want when users add values to this field, wordpress automatically add that value to tag list and then print that value. Is there anyone that can help me write a code to do that? I'd be glad.

I have tried this `$tag_name = get_field('custom_field'); 
get_tag($tag_name);` didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
$custom_field = get_field( 'custom_field' ); //get ACF value
$custom_field_slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $custom_field );

wp_insert_term(
    $custom_field, // ACF value 
    'your-taxonomy', // your taxonomy
        array(
            'description'=> 'any description',
            'slug' => strtolower( $custom_field_slug ),
        )
);


$term = get_term_by( 'slug', strtolower( $custom_field ), 'your-taxonomy' ); 
//echo "<pre>"; print_r( $term );
```

You will get whole object

Comment: I'm not getting anything. Just for double check. I should change ```'your-taxonomy'``` to ```'tag'``` and put the field name in ```get_filed();``` I did that and didn't show anything

Comment: change `your-taxonomy` to `post_tag`

Comment: it added the tag to tag list. thanks for that. ```echo "<pre>"``` and ```print_r($term)``` didn't work. I used ```echo $custom_field``` and it shows the value. problem is it's not a link. I want if the user clicks on the value it takes them to the tag page.

Comment: `echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $term ->term_id ) ) . '" class="btn">' . $term ->name . '</a>';` you can try this

Comment: Also you need to replace space with dash in `slug`. check my edit in above answer

Comment: you are the best. everything works fine now. can you please tell me what does this ```esc_url( get_category_link( $term ->term_id ) )``` exactly mean? just want to understand the code so if I wanted to use it in other parts of my website I don't have to ask for solution again.

Comment: you can check this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_link/)